# Wrong time when adding event to iCal programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, icalendar

I was trying to add an ical event using this code.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = title;

event.startDate = date;
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:5000 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Where date is something **2011-09-30 20:30:00 +0000**

The event go added on date 1st October with time 2 AM, it is very strange.

I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: you need end date After 50000sec startdate is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking in account the timeZone.

**2011-09-30 20:30:00 +0000** the **+0000** means GTM, if you set a to plus 4 hours you will get 2011-10-01 02:30:00 +0400 which is the date you are getting.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. I want the event should be added to exact date and time despite user's location/time zone. any suggestion ?

Comment: You need to get the users timezone, with out it you can't really set it the a exact date and time.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right.  I just added **NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];** to the date I am adding, it came correct for my timezone but when I changed iPhone timezone, the timings went wrong. any suggestion ?

Comment: No, if an event is enter en the user changes there timezone then the event keeps there old timezine, it just the way it works.

Comment: I removed the old event and re added the event while changed the timezone.. The timing went wrong..